# Programatically change the value of the @click method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Here is an element with a `@click` handler:

```
<button @click="doSomething">doSomething</button>
```

Inside this element, how can we programatically change the value of `doSomething` with `doSomethingElse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the function that you want as the handler in a variable.

In this example, `handler` is the click handler for the first button. Clicking the second and third buttons changes the function that `handler` is set to.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      handler: this.doSomething,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      console.log('something')
    },
    doSomethingElse() {
      console.log('something else')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="handler">Fire Click Handler</button>
  <button @click="handler = doSomething">Make Handler Do Something</button>
  <button @click="handler = doSomethingElse">Make Handler Do Something Else</button>
</div>
```